# ROS Rviz: How to display grid

Tags: python, c++, ros

raspberry pi 4, ubuntu 20, ros noetic

When I was run rviz , it's displayed by picture below.

[rviz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQf6U.jpg)

How do I make it show the grid?
And why my rviz displat like that.

I’m not good in English, please forgive me if I make a few mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The grid that is shown along with the default rviz file comes from the `Grid` display element you see on the left hand side. If you would like to make the grid larger edit the `Plane Cell Count` field to a higher number. It should be noted this is a static grid and if you would like to overlap it with data that's in another frame, you may have to edit the `Offset` field.